# urllib3 segfault (core dumped)

Tags: python, linux, segmentation-fault, urllib3

I'm getting a segfault ("Illegal operation (core dumped)") for a python program that I've run every week without fault for ages. I'm also running Ubuntu on Nitrous. I recall dealing with these yonks ago when coding in C, and I haven't had to deal with them very much recently.

Importing the library urllib3 seems to be causing the problem. Does anyone know a fix?

Also, can someone advise or link to the best workflow for diagnosing these problems in future?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example to demonstrate your problem (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

> "Illegal operation"

This *usually* means that you are running code compiled for a more capable processor (e.g. [Haswell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture))) on a less capable one (e.g. [Ivy Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_(microarchitecture))).

> Importing the library urllib3 seems to be causing the problem.

On my Ubuntu machine, `import urllib3` loads `libssl.so.1.0.0`, `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` and `_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. These crypto libraries are very likely to be compiled with [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), [AVX2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#Advanced_Vector_Extensions_2), etc. instructions which your processor may not support.

> best workflow for diagnosing these problems

Your first step should be to find out which instruction is causing the `SIGILL`. To do so, run:

```
gdb python
(gdb) run
>>> import urllib3  # do whatever is necessary to reproduce SIGILL
(gdb) x/i $pc
(gdb) info sym $pc
```

The last two commands above should give you the instruction that is causing the `SIGILL`, and the library in which that instruction is used. Once you know what that instruction is, you can verify that your processor doesn't support it, and contact the distributor of the "guilty" library to get a different compilation (one without using instructions that are not supported by your CPU).